# How to number atoms using chemfig?

Tags: positioning, chemfig

I need to number atoms using `chemfig`. I thought I could use `\chembelow` and `\chemabove` to place numbers above and below but adding these commands changes the look of the drawing and does not simply only add the number.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{*6(\chembelow{}{1}=\chembelow{}{5}-\chembelow{}{9}(*6(-=-=-=-=))--=\chemabove{}{2}-)}

\end{document}
```

[image: Chemfig example]

The lines are broken where the numbers are added. How can I add numbers without breaking the lines? Also, the numbers are placed very close -- could that be related?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use invisible bonds:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\definesubmol\QQ{-[,0.2,,,draw=none]\scriptstyle}
\chemfig{*6((!\QQ1)=(!\QQ5)-(-[6,0.2,,,draw=none]\scriptstyle9)*6(-=-=-=)-[,,,,draw=none]-=(!\QQ2)-)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

- To avoid breaking the lines, create an empty bond and attach it
- To raise or lower an argument of `\chemabove` or `\chembelow`, use the optional argument

The `chemfig` manual recommends `\definesubmol\nobond{[,0.2,,,draw=none]}` in *12.2 Add a superscript without modifying a bond* and using this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\definesubmol\nobond{[,0.2,,,draw=none]}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6((!\nobond\chembelow[1ex]{}{1})=
  (!\nobond\chembelow[1ex]{}{5})-(!\nobond\chembelow[1ex]{}{9})
  (*6(-=-=-=-=))--=(!\nobond\chemabove[1ex]{}{2})-)}
\end{document}
```

[image: numbered atoms]