# Can I annotate the links in chemfig?

Tags: chemfig

`chemfig` is really great chemical picture editor, but just one problem doesn't allow me to continue the work.

In the picture below, you see the chemical picture from the book with numbered links and framed **CH_3** radicals. Is these feature available in the `chemfig` package?

[image: Chemical image example]

Comment: You may want to have a look at [How to number atoms using chemfig?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36829/5049) and [How to modify just some nodes' styles in chemfig](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50862/5049)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the best way... The code below sets marks in the molecule using `chemfig`'s `@{<nodename>}` syntax and then uses these marks with `\chemmove` (which basically is a `{tikzpicture}` with options `remember picture, overlay`) to add dashed rectangles. The main chain is numbered using a submol, similar to [unbonpetit's answer to How to number atoms using chemfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36836/5049)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\definesubmol{\nr}{-[:120,.3,,,draw=none]\scriptstyle}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{
  CH_3-[@{me3,.1}]CH(-[2]C_2H_5(!\nr{7, 8}))(!\nr6)
  -CH([6]-[@{iPr}]CH(-[0]CH_3)-CH_3)(!\nr5)
  -CH([2]-[@{tBu}]C(-[:30]CH_3)(-[:150]H_3C)-CH_3)(!\nr4)
  -CH_2(!\nr3)-C(-[@{me2,.9}2]CH_3)(-[@{me1,.9}6]CH_3)(!\nr2)
  -CH_3!\nr1
}
\chemmove{
  \draw[dashed]
    ([xshift=-8pt,yshift=-8pt]iPr) rectangle ++(2.3,-1.6)
    ([xshift=-1.6cm]tBu) rectangle ++(3.2cm,2cm)
    ([xshift=-5pt]me1) rectangle ++(.75,-.5)
    ([xshift=-5pt]me2) rectangle ++(.75,.5)
    ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-7pt]me3) rectangle ++(-.75,.5) ;
}
\end{document}
```

[image]